# Remove controller action name from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having what I feel might be a simple issue but am kind struggling with it. I have an action in my Controller that downloads a pdf when a button is clicked in the View. The PDF download but the issue is after I click it the action remains in the browser and downloads the PDF every time I reload the page.

**Example of URL**

Before I click button

```
https://matrix-spam-camp.c9users.io
```

After I click of the button this stays in URL until I delete it manually from the browser.

```
https://matrix-spam-camp.c9users.io/download_pdf
```

/app/app/views/portfolio/main.html.erb  (link)

```
<%= link_to download_pdf_path, class: 'download-btn', remote: true do %>
    <%= image_tag('img_btn_icon.png') %> <span class='resume-btn-text'>Resume</span>
<% end %>
```

/app/app/controllers/portfolio_controller.rb

```
def download_pdf
  send_file "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/docs/resume.pdf", type: "application/pdf", x_sendfile: true
end
```

/app/config/routes.rb

```
get 'download_pdf', to: "portfolio#download_pdf"
```

Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried removing the remote true from the link?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, its been doing this before I added remote: true.

Comment: then maybe it's the remote true that isn't working, do you have `//= require rails-ujs` on your application.js file? do you have other remote parts on your application that are working as expected?

Comment: Yes, I have `//= require rails-ujs` in application.js. No, I this is the only remote item so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by adding a `target: _blank` to the `link_to`.

```
<%= link_to :download, class: 'download-btn', target: "_blank" do %>
    <%= image_tag('img_btn_icon.png') %> <span class='resume-btn-text'>Resume</span>
<% end %>
```

This prevents the download button from applying the name for the controller action being called by the `link_to` from being placed in the browsers URL.